# JAVA_HOME in Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

i have installed jdk1.6 with netbeans 6.9 in my ubuntu10.10
it works fine ,i then try eclipse but it shows me the jdk or jre kit must be available to run eclipse.
i set  JAVA_HOME AND PATH IN MY /etc/enviroment file

```
`PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr`/games:$PATH:$JAVA_HOME:$JAVA_HOME/bin"

JAVA_HOME="/home/amit/jdk1.6.0_24"
CLASSPATH="/home/amit/jdk1.6.0_24/lib:."
```

but it doesn,t work
`java -version` command did not work
`echo $java _ home` works
i also restart my pc.
i also change it

```
JAVA_HOME="/home/amit/jdk1.6.0_24"
`PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr`/games:$PATH:$JAVA_HOME:$JAVA_HOME/bin"

CLASSPATH="/home/amit/jdk1.6.0_24/lib:."
```

but it still did not work
thanks in advance

Comment: What is the backtick \` before PATH meant for? Note: In shellscripts, you don't mark Strings with quotes, but you prevent wordsplitting with quotes. So if your PATH/CLASSPATH doesn't contain a space or other WS, you needn't quote it.

Comment: @user unknown - While quotes aren't required, it's often considered good form for consistency's sake, as you will otherwise have a mix of quoted and unquoted strings scattered throughout. You should always quote variable names when referencing them (which are often joined with strings), and quotes wont have to be added later when you need to add a whitespace, or special character.

Comment: Well, but it isn't a string, but a path, and your case is a clear indication, why obsessive usage of quotes is dangerous - it leads to wrong conclusions. People don't learn, why quotes are used, and when they are needed, and decorate their code like a christmas tree - it gets a ritual to avoid thinking.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have the definition of JAVA_HOME before the defintion of PATH.  The expansion needs to take place at definition time, else it looks for the folder named "$JAVA_HOME" which you probably do not have.

Comment: You have backticks in your PATH definition.  They need to go.  You also need to export the defined variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $java _ home
```

is wrong.

- blanks aren't optional
- we are case-sensitive

  echo $JAVA_HOME

is the right way.